# Razor/ASP.Net Core web code block not distinguishing html vs variables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having a horrible time figuring out why this code will not pick up the declared variable isThumbNail(). The long term plan is to add the class border-dark (or similar) if it is the current thumbnail. I am getting a "Use of undeclared variable" red squiggle under the line containing:

```
@(isThumbNail ? "border-dark" : "")
```

I've tried wrapping the entire code block in @{} wrapping the offending variable in @{} and @(), starting the line of html with @:, adding < p > and < text > tags to the front of the line and pretty much every other trick in my toolbox.

```
            <div class="row">
            <div class="column col-12 ml-3 mt-3">
                @if (Model != null)
                {
                    bool isThumbNail;
                    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Images.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (Model.Images[i].Filename == Model.ThumbNail)
                        { isThumbNail = true; }
                        var photoPath = "~/images/" + (Model.Images[i].Filename ?? "noimage.jpg");
  // offending line     <text><img class="img-fluid rounded @(isThumbNail ? "border-dark" : "")" height="50" width="50" src="@photoPath" alt="" asp-append-version="true"></text>
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Images.Count; i++)
    {
        bool isThumbNail = Model.Images[i].Filename == Model.ThumbNail
        var photoPath = "~/images/" + (Model.Images[i].Filename ?? "noimage.jpg");
        string klass = "img-fluid rounded" + ( isThumbnail ? " border-dark" : "" );

        <img class="@klass" height="50" width="50" src="@photoPath" alt="" asp-append-version="true" />

    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I spent so much time trying to force razor to work it out, that I didn't try concatenating it all into a string. Thank you.